# ssh wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby, api, object, ssh

Referencing the [net-ssh API](http://net-ssh.rubyforge.org/), what's the "best" way to pass connection parameters which come from a yaml?

error:

```
thufir@dur:~/ruby$ 
thufir@dur:~/ruby$ ruby ssh.rb 
{:host=>"localhost", :user=>"me", :port=>123, :password=>"mypassword"}
/home/thufir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/net-ssh-2.6.8/lib/net/ssh.rb:165:in `start': wrong number of arguments (1 for 2..3) (ArgumentError)
    from ssh.rb:14:in `<main>'
thufir@dur:~/ruby$
```

code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'net/ssh'
require 'yaml'
require 'pry'

conn = YAML.load_file('conn.yml')

params = {:host => conn['host'], :user => conn['user'], 
          :port => conn['port'],:password => conn['password']}

puts params

Net::SSH.start(params) do |ssh|
  puts 'hi'
end
```

yaml:

```
user: me
password: mypassword
port: 123
host: localhost
```

is it possible to just pass one monolithic object?  Or, do you have to break it up into host, user, et. al.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `host` and `user` arguments must be specified as positional arguments, not as part of the `options` hash. Thus:

```
Net::SSH.start(conn['host'], conn['user'], port: conn['port'], password: conn['password']) do |ssh|
  # ...
end
```

Or you can just pass through all the YAML key-value pairs directly:

```
Net::SSH.start(conn.delete('host'), conn.delete('user'), conn) do |ssh|
  # ...
end
```

Comment: that's wild, didn't know you could pass the YAML key-value pairs raw like that!  I can't really test it, because I don't think my server allows ssh, but that's very interesting.  Wouldn't it be a better API if you could pass it all as one hash?  Seems odd, the positional arguments.